# yii Property "CWebUser.bootstrap" is not defined and can't access gii

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, iunknown

I have a site using the yii framework. As the first thing, after i got the site up and running, I wanted to install bootstrap (yii-bootstrap-2.1.0.r355.zip). This, however, did not go very smooth.

I get the following error "Property "CWebUser.bootstrap" is not defined."

The Bootstrap extension is placed as /blog/protected/extensions/bootstrap

My main config file looks like this

```
<?php

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.

Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/bootstrap');


return array(
'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
'name'=>'be creative',
'theme'=>'bootstrap', // requires you to copy the theme under your themes directory

// preloading 'log' component
'preload'=>array('log'),
// preloading bootstrap component
'preload'=>array('bootstrap'),

// autoloading model and component classes
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
),

'defaultController'=>'post',

// application components
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        'bootstrap' => array('class'=>'ext.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap')
    ),

    // gii module...        
    'modules'=>array(
        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'admin',
            'generatorPaths'=>array('bootstrap.gii')
        ),
    ),

    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'sqlite:protected/data/blog.db',
        'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
    ),
    // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database

    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '123',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
    ),

    'errorHandler'=>array(
        // use 'site/error' action to display errors
        'errorAction'=>'site/error',
    ),
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            'post/<id:\d+>/<title:.*?>'=>'post/view',
            'posts/<tag:.*?>'=>'post/index',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
    'log'=>array(
        'class'=>'CLogRouter',
        'routes'=>array(
            array(
                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                'levels'=>'error, warning',
            ),
            // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
            /*
            array(
                'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
            ),
            */
        ),
    ),
),

// application-level parameters that can be accessed
// using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
'params'=>require(dirname(__FILE__).'/params.php'),
```

);

Comment: While this won't directly fix your problem/answer your question I suggest you use [Yiistrap](http://www.getyiistrap.com) instead of Yii-Bootstrap. It is essentially a refactor of the latter.

Comment: now i'm getting the following error...:(Internal Server Error Property "CWebApplication.db" is read only. An internal error occurred while the Web server was processing your request. Please contact the webmaster to report this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified invalid `components` configuration:

1. `user` component is used for authentication.
2. you need specify `bootstrap` component

   ```
   'components'=>array(
       'user'=>array(
           'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
           'class' => 'WebUser'    //if you expanded CWebUser Yii class
       ),
       'bootstrap'=>array(
           'class'=>'ext.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
       ),
   ),
   ```

Comment: now i'm getting the following error...:(Internal Server Error
Property "CWebApplication.db" is read only.

An internal error occurred while the Web server was processing your request. Please contact the webmaster to report this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: I think, you get this error, because you specified the db connection twice

Comment: thank u but i'm defined db only once in the main.php

Comment: In your posted ``main.php`` config, the db connection was specified twice. Once for sqlite, second for mysql.